# Why does the value of request.user appear to be inconsistent?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am wanting an application to be able to check whether the user that is currently logged in is "test2". I'm using Django and running the following code:

```
<script>
      console.log('{{ request.user }}')

      {% if request.user == "test2" %}
        console.log('The user that is currently logged in is test2.')

      {% else %}
        console.log('There was an error.')

      {% endif %}
</script>
```

And my console is logging the following:

```
test2
There was an error.
```

Why is this? How do I get the application to recognise that "test2" is logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

request.user.username

```
<script>
      console.log('{{ request.user.username }}')

      {% if request.user.username == "test2" %}
        console.log('The user that is currently logged in is test2.')

      {% else %}
        console.log('There was an error.')

      {% endif %}
</scrip
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be because `request.user` is actully object, but `__str__` is giving `username` attribute of `User`. So:

```
{% if request.user.username == "test2" %}
    console.log('The user that is currently logged in is test2.')
{% else %}
    console.log('There was an error.')
{% endif %}
```

*Note:- I am assuming `test2` is *username* and it is *unique*.

Answer (score 2):

Since the logic is in template, it is being evaluated at server side. This means that `request.user` is not a string, it is a `user` instance.

The reason why the `console.log('{{ request.user }}')` prints out the username is when you print, `__str__` is called which returns the `username`.

So you need to check with the correct field, i.e. the `user.username`.

```
<script>
      console.log('{{ request.user }}')

      {% if request.user.username == "test2" %}
        console.log('The user that is currently logged in is test2.')

      {% else %}
        console.log('There was an error.')

      {% endif %}
</script>
```